# Adding visibility toggle to material design component in HTML, Javascript project?

Tags: javascript, angular-material, material-design

Following is a material design password field with a button on the right. When you click the button, it toggles visibility of the password entered.

[image]

I have a pure HTML+Javascript+Jquery project.

This is how I import Material Design into my project:

```
<head>
  <script src="assets/js/vendors/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

  <!--- Materialize Component-->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://unpkg.com/material-components-web@latest/dist/material-components-web.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/material-components-web@latest/dist/material-components-web.min.js"></script>
  ...
</head>
```

How can I generate following material design component in my project?

[image: password field]

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

```js
$(document).on("click", "fieldset > button.toggle-password", function(){
  $(this).siblings("input").prop("type", (index, type) => type === "password" ? "text" : "password");
});
```

```css
fieldset {
  border-color: blue;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

fieldset legend {
  color: blue;
}

fieldset input {
  border: none;
  display: inline-block;
  width: calc(100% - 50px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<fieldset>
  <legend>Enter your password</legend>
  <input type="password" value="p4ssw0rd"/>
  <button class="toggle-password" type="button">eye</button>
</fieldset>
```

yes, I know, this could look nicer; but you get the idea/structure.